# Calling __exit_ after GradientTape(persistent=True)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, automatic-differentiation, gradienttape

I start recording the gradients with `tf.GradientTape(persistent=True)` in order be able to call `gradient_tape.gradient()` more than one time. Since this means that the gradients are not being released after calling the `gradient()` method, do I have to call something like `__exit__` at the end of `train_step` ?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape:

> By default, the resources held by a GradientTape are released as soon
> as GradientTape.gradient() method is called. To compute multiple
> gradients over the same computation, create a persistent gradient
> tape. This allows multiple calls to the gradient() method as resources
> are released when the tape object is garbage collected.

After train step, as long as no other object has a reference to that tape, the garbage collector will collect it.